# Why do we need @PUT, @POST @DELETE annotations? My code works without them

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have methods using `@PUT`, `@POST` annotations. Without these annotations these methods work well. Then what is the need of these annotations?

```
@GET    
@Path ("/{stockId}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public StockDetail search(@PathParam("stockId") Integer stockId) {

    final String methodName="search";
    mLogger.debug(mClassName+"::" +methodName+"::Entered");
    StockDetail stockDetails=null;
    try {

         stockDetails = mStockBean.retrieve(stockId);
    } catch(Exception exception) {

        mLogger.error("ClassName::" +mClassName+ "MethodName::" +methodName+"Error::"+exception.getMessage());
    }
    return stockDetails;
}
```

Comment: I think they are used by spring-mvc for creating webservices out of java methods.

Comment: No i am using Resteasy to call the EJB methods

Comment: Then RestEasy is using those annotations to create REST webservices out of Java methods.

Answer (score 3):

well, these annotations allows you, for example, to have the same path for different methods:

```
@GET    
@Path ("/{stockId}")
@Produces("application/xml")
```

and

```
@PUT
@Path ("/{stockId}")
@Consumes("application/xml")
```

Here, fore the same path we will have the different type of request.

UPD. according to comment I will note that if we have method `A()` and we use it for `@GET`with the web-service signature as declared above, then we use it without any params (because it does not consume any request body). And for the second one we will use the method `A(String body)` because we consume some entity to handle.

Comment: As we can't define same method name twice except in case of overloading. In the given example, the url will be same for both case if the parameter and no of parameter is same i.e. not acceptable by compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Annotations provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. They have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.

Quote from [the Java Tutorial by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html):

> Annotations have a number of uses, among them:
>
> 1. Information for the compiler — Annotations can be used by the compiler
>         to detect errors or suppress warnings.
> 2. Compiler-time and deployment-time processing — Software tools can process 
>        annotation information to generate code, XML files, and so forth.
> 3. Runtime processing — Some annotations are available to be examined at runtime.

Annotations won't effect the working of the method